# Weird object found in garage

Tags: garage

I was working with my father in the garage and we were cleaning up the boxes in the section above the garage door. I found three green rods, two had smaller rods sticking out the sides and two did not.

I'm not sure what the purpose of these are, they didn't have a buyers tag or anything on it to my knowledge. Is it common?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about identifying an object that is unrelated to home improvement.

Comment: A hammock frame? Are you saying a hammock is not something the average person has at their homes?

Comment: @ytpillai I'd say a hammock is not something  that the *average* person has. Also, just because an object is used in/at a home, does not  make it related to do-it-yourself home improvement.

Comment: I apologise then. I chose this forum because I wasn't sure what the object even was and I found it in the garage. I'll agree to closing it since it is solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like pieces of a hammock frame.

Comment: Definitely fits the description. Also explains why it might be in the garage, because our house has a small, shared backyard with a forest and a trampoline and a playground so previous owners may have moved it from their previous house and forgotten about it. Thanks!